# hooking libhoudini on x86 emulator

Tags: x86, linux, android, frida

I'm trying to hook libhoudini to debug an application instruction by instruction using frida but frida not supports it i need a example on how can this be achieved!
I'm using a x86 emulator to run arm JNI libs which is ofcource translated to x86 by libhoudini problem is that i can't see those instructions when i hook the app
look at [this](https://github.com/nevermoe/EHook)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's true. So far, Frida 12.11.14 does not support it.

You can check https://www.slideshare.net/cisoplatform7/one-step-ahead-of-cheaters-instrumenting-android-emulators
not sure if it's working...